# Styling the autocomplete dropdown to work with the up/down arrow keys

Tags: ajax

The following custom styling for drupal core's autocomplete dropdown works when hovering, but it is ignored when using the up/down arrow keys. (Currently, pressing the arrow keys only turns the text white.)

Does anybody know the secret to getting styles and keypresses working together?

```
#autocomplete li:hover, #autocomplete li:focus{ 
background-color:#428bca;
color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
#autocomplete li.selected { 
  background-color:#428bca;
  color:green;
}
```

The items from the autocomplete list are having the *.selected* class added on hover/key navigation.